# Frequey ethernet/wifi connection drop in ubuntu16.04

Tags: networking

Hey I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on hp 15-ac149tx machine. I am facing frequent ethernet and wifi connection drop where each connection lasts only 5-10 minutes after which I have to disconnect and reconnect. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here are few system details

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:80c2]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
--
13:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

2

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  0
ccm                    20480  0
rfcomm                 69632  0
appletalk              36864  0
ipx                    28672  0
p8023                  16384  1 ipx
p8022                  16384  1 ipx
psnap                  16384  2 ipx,appletalk
llc                    16384  2 p8022,psnap
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm                   536576  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
uvcvideo               90112  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
aesni_intel           167936  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    81920  1
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
hp_wmi                 16384  0
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_soc_rt286          36864  0
arc4                   16384  2
rtl8723be              86016  0
snd_soc_ssm4567        16384  0
snd_soc_rl6347a        16384  1 snd_soc_rt286
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_ssm4567,snd_soc_rt286
btusb                  45056  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723be
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
btintel                16384  1 btusb
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_rt286,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
mei_me                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
acpi_pad               20480  0
snd                    81920  23 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
8250_dw                16384  0
dw_dmac                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
int3403_thermal        16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
int3402_thermal        16384  0
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
int3400_thermal        16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  3 int3402_thermal,processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
shpchp                 36864  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
amdkfd                122880  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
radeon               1511424  1
i915                 1208320  6
ttm                    98304  1 radeon
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,radeon
psmouse               126976  0
drm_kms_helper        139264  2 i915,radeon
ahci                   36864  3
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
drm                   360448  10 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,radeon
mii                    16384  1 r8169
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
video                  40960  1 i915
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  1 i2c_hid
fjes                   28672  0
```

3.

```
ifconfig
enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:5a:0f:65:54:0f  
          inet addr:10.243.134.98  Bcast:10.243.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:159585 errors:0 dropped:18 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:97793 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:191672513 (191.6 MB)  TX bytes:12094654 (12.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6548 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6548 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:605084 (605.0 KB)  TX bytes:605084 (605.0 KB)

wlp19s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:1c:a8:2b:07:d1  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:277 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1621 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:123854 (123.8 KB)  TX bytes:194848 (194.8 KB)
```

Comment: Check your DHCP lease timeout/duration.  In _some_ cases, all connections are dropped when the lease is re-acquired. Generally depends on the router, in my experience.

Comment: Hey, I checked DHCP lease timeout. It is 1 day.  further more my all other devices are working fine.